# Polly with cancellation token is not working for synchronous thread

Tags: c#, timeout, polly, retry-logic, policywrap

I'm new to Polly so there may be a completely different approach compared to the one I'm trying to do and that would be perfectly OK.
My goals are this:

1. I am using timeout strategy as: `TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic`
2. I want to timeout the call for given `clientTimeOut`
3. I am using cancellation token to timeout the thread

I am using cancellation token to timeout the call but somehow the below code is not working. I am not creating a new thread while adding a cancellation token but using the same thread to honoured the timeout.
Does it always need to add the cancellation token in asynchronous call i.e. `ExecuteAsync()` or use another thread for it ?
Can someone help me with what is wrong with the below code and why timeout is not working?

**Note:** Using `TimeoutStrategy.Pessimist` will work for me but I can’t use this due to some other usecase. I need to read the https headers from request context, and we will loose this information when using async call. Hence I need to use the sync call.

```
public TResult ExecuteWrapper<TResult>(Func<CancellationToken ,TResult> func)
{
    int attempts = 0;
    int retryCounter = 3;
    int waitTime = 1000;
    int clientTimeOut = 10000;
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
    var cancellationToken = cts.Token;

    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().Retry(retryCounter);
    retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetry(retryCounter, sleepDurationProvider: attempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(this.waitTime), onRetry: (exception, timeSpan) =>
    {
          logRetryException(timeSpan, attempts++, exception);
    });
    
    PolicyWrap retrypolicywrap = retryPolicy.Wrap(Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(clientTimeOut), TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic));
    return retrypolicywrap.Execute(func, cancellationToken);
} 

public void BaseFunction(){
   var result = ExecuteWrapper(() => DummyFunctionToSleepTheThread())
}

public string DummyFunctionToSleepTheThread(){
   //Reading http header from the request context
   //which will lost if we use async call 
   //Hence we can't use Task.Delay(milliseconds) here.
    int milliseconds = 15000;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

I tried adding the cancellation token but it did not honoured the timeout.

Comment: Signaling a cancelation will not preempt or abort a `Sleep` or any other operation. Cancelation is cooperative. In general it is a very bad idea just to abort a thread. [How to cancel a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [optimistic timeout strategy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#optimistic-timeout) to cancel a `Thread`. This strategy uses the co-operative behaviour of the `CancellationToken`. `Thread`s [do not natively support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) `CancellationToken` like `Task`s.

So, you have two options. Fall back to [pessimistic timeout strategy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#pessimistic-timeout) or use `Task` instead of `Thread`.

As far as I can tell from the your code you haven't designed your solution to take advantage of `Task`s and async-await. So, try to use the pessimistic strategy.

---

**UPDATE #1**

Here is a simple app which demonstrates the difference

(*Please note that [bellow overload of Timeout](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/ff2ec4c467cba2456ec01b498af1e7b768561465/src/Polly/Timeout/TimeoutSyntax.cs#L30) requires **seconds** not milliseconds*)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var optimisticTimeout = Policy.Timeout(1, TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic);
    optimisticTimeout.Execute(ToBeDecoratedMethod);
    var pessimisticTimeout = Policy.Timeout(1, TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic);
    try
    {
        pessimisticTimeout.Execute(() => ToBeDecoratedMethod());
    }
    catch(TimeoutRejectedException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timed out");
    }
}

public static void ToBeDecoratedMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before Sleep");
    Thread.Sleep(1_500);
    Console.WriteLine("After Sleep");
}
```

The output will be:

```
Before Sleep
After Sleep
Before Sleep
Timed out
```

The working code can be found on [this dotnet fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x38sEL).